# Bing SDS Geofence Schema

Tags: geolocation, geocoding, geospatial, bing-maps, geofencing

I have created and published a data source with Bing SDS but it is a singular point and am wondering how to create a data source that defines an area?

Essentially I need a geo-fence around a certain point. Below is what my schema currently looks like, what parameters do I need to add to it to define an area?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <MainRoot>
  <xs:schema id="FourthCoffeeShops_ds" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="FourthCoffeeShops_ds" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="FourthCoffeeShops">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="EntityID" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="AddressLine" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Locality" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="AdminDistrict" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="PostalCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="CountryRegion" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Phone" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Manager" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Latitude" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Longitude" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Confidence" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:unique name="Constraint1" msdata:PrimaryKey="true">
        <xs:selector xpath=".//FourthCoffeeShops" />
        <xs:field xpath="EntityID" />
      </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
<FourthCoffeeShops>
  <EntityID>1000</EntityID>
  <AddressLine>1 Microsoft Way</AddressLine>
  <Locality>Redmond</Locality>
  <AdminDistrict>WA</AdminDistrict>
  <PostalCode>98052</PostalCode>
  <Phone>303-555-0188</Phone>
  <Manager>Alan Steiner</Manager>
  <Latitude>47.640049</Latitude>
  <Longitude>-122.129797</Longitude>
  <Confidence>High</Confidence>
</FourthCoffeeShops>
<FourthCoffeeShops>
  <EntityID>1001</EntityID>
  <AddressLine>1 Microsoft Way</AddressLine>
  <Locality>Redmond</Locality>
  <AdminDistrict>WA</AdminDistrict>
  <PostalCode>98052</PostalCode>
  <CountryRegion>United States</CountryRegion>
  <Phone>425-555-0111</Phone>
  <Manager>Phil Spencer</Manager>
  <Latitude>47.639767</Latitude>
  <Longitude>-122.129959</Longitude>
  <Confidence>Medium</Confidence>
</FourthCoffeeShops>
</MainRoot>
```

To be clear by an area I mean a certain radius around a location or a polygon that contains the location.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a column that is of type "Edm.Geography" or "xs:anyType". This property type takes in Well Known Text, a standard way of representing spatial shapes as text. This allows you to store common spatial shapes such as Point, LineString, Polygon, Multipoint, MultiLineString, MultiPolygon, GeometryCollection. Here is the documentation around this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg585138.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn436149.aspx

To represent a GeoFence you will want to create a Polygon that represents the area you want. If you want to represent a circle you will need to calculate the points that approximate the circle: http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/02/09/Virtual-Earth-Draw-a-Circle-Radius-Around-a-LatLong-Point

Here is a blog post on using Geofences stored in SDS with tracked devices: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bingdevcenter/archive/2014/04/03/geo-fencing-with-bing-spatial-data-services-and-azure-mobile-services.aspx